# After postback page fails with DBContext error at Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am running into a problem where, after a postback, the page is failing to load due to

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

I have stepped through the code and the .cs file code works fine, it throwing the error in the .cshtml file on

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Section, Model.Sections, "--Select Section--", new { @id = "Section", disabled = "disabled" })<br /><br />`

so I am a bit confused as how this is happening since the .cshtml file is not calling into the context but the model. Here is the backend code

```
using (CharacterContext db = new CharacterContext())
{
    model.Sections = new SelectList(db.Sections.OrderBy(s => s.Title), "ID", "Title");

    if (!FileHelper.IsImage(RaceImageFile))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Invalid File Type.", "Images must be JPG, GIF, or PNG files.");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (RaceImageFile != null)
        {
            string FolderName = GeneralHelper.GetSectionRoute(model.Section) + "/Races";
            model.RaceImageID = FileHelper.UploadSiteImage(FolderName, model.Name, RaceImageFile, model.RaceImageID.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            if (model.RaceImageID.HasValue)
            {
                FileHelper.UpdateFileName(model.Name, model.RaceImageID.Value);
            }
        }

        Race UpdatedRace = new Race()
        {
            ID = model.ID,
            Name = model.Name,
            SectionID = model.Section,
            RaceImageID = model.RaceImageID,
            Description = model.Description
        };

        db.Entry(UpdatedRace).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.Results = "Race updated.";
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `SelectList` only [expects an `IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), I suspect that it's not actually *enumerating* the values right away, but rather waiting until it's rendered by the view.  And by the time that happens, the DB context is disposed so this can't be enumerated:

```
db.Sections.OrderBy(s => s.Title)
```

Basically, the execution of that expression is deferred until the values are enumerated, which in this case is too late.

You can explicitly enumerate the values right away by materializing the expression into a list:

```
db.Sections.OrderBy(s => s.Title).ToList()
```

So the whole line would be:

```
model.Sections = new SelectList(db.Sections.OrderBy(s => s.Title).ToList(), "ID", "Title");
```

In this particular case this wouldn't be a big deal.  But keep in mind that `.ToList()` isn't always to be used so lightly on database operations because it can sometimes pull back a *lot* more from the database than you actually want (by materializing the records before the rest of the expression tree is invoked), which hurts performance.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to avoid using `using` with contexts, since it pretty much borks all the lazy-loading functionality of Entity Framework. There's a reason why you don't see `using` in any of the ASP.NET MVC examples dealing with the database.

If you do use it, then you have to be very careful that all the data you intend to use on page is eagerly-loaded *before* you return from your action. That's not a bad thing, per se, as it keeps you cognizant of things that may be lazy-loading without your knowledge, but it's a real pain, I assure you.

The "best practice" approach, assuming you're going to work directly with your context in your controller, is to set an instance variable on your controller for your context:

```
private readonly CharacterContext db = new CharacterContext();
```

Then, in the `Dispose` method of your controller:

```
db.Dispose();
```

`Controller` implements `IDisposable`, and is newed up and disposed for each request, so your context's lifetime is per request as well.